# Algorithm maths quiz + write to a text file

Tags: python, quiz

Are there any ways I can clean this code up to make it more user-friendly?

```
import random #Random Function
import os

print("What is your name?") #Asking User Name
name = input().title() #.title() capitilises the first letter in each word, so when the name is printed in later code the first letter will always be capitilised.
class_name = input("Which class do you wish to input results for? ")
print (name, ", Welcome to the OCR Controlled Assessment Maths Test") 
score = 0  #Set Score to 0
question = 0 #Set Question Number to 0
while question < 10: #After 10 Questions, it will stop asking the user questions.
    operator = random.randint(1,3)#Addition,Multiplication,Subtraction
    num1 = random.randint(1,25)#Random Number between 1 and 10 to be used in the questions
    num2 = random.randint(1,25)#Random Number between 1 and 10 to be used in the questions
    if operator == 1: #If Random Operator = 1, it will ask addition questions
        print("What is", num1, "+", num2)
        ans = num1 + num2

    elif operator == 2:#If Random Operator = 2, it will ask multiplication questions
        print("What is", num1, "*", num2)
        ans = num1 * num2

    else: #If Random Operator = 3/Else, it will ask subtraction questions.
        print("What is", num1, "-", num2)
        ans = num1 - num2

    while True:
      try:
        user_ans = int(input()) #The Answer the user inputs to the question asked
      except ValueError: #When anything but a interger is inputted.
        print ("That is not a valid answer")
        continue #Dosen't print Invalid Code Error
      else:
        break

    if user_ans == ans: #If user answer matches that of the question
        print("Correct")
        score += 1

    else: #If user answer dosen't match that of a question.
        print("Incorrect")



    question += 1 #When a question is answered, it will +1 until it equals 10 at which point it will stop.

print("Well done", name, "you scored", score, "/10") #Print Final Score out of 10


class_name = class_name + ".txt"    #adds '.txt' to the end of the file so it can be used to create a file under the name a user specifies

file = open(class_name , 'a')   #opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
name = (name)
file.write(str(name + " : " )) #writes the information to the file
file.write(str(score))
file.write('\n')
file.close()    #safely closes the file to save the information

viewscore = input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class").lower()

if viewscore == "yes".lower():
    f = open(class_name, 'r')
    file_contents = f.read()
    print (file_contents)
    f.close()

elif viewscore != "yes".lower():
    print ("Press any key to exit")
    ex = input ("")
    os._exit(0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Your question is on the balance of being off-topic here. You can't ask `add additional functions` since we review existing code or implementing a new aspect in the code (the sort by alphanumeric). I would suggest you to clean your question of those elements. I would suggest you to visit the [help] to better know how to ask a question here.

Comment: Who is the "user" you want it to be friendlier for? The person taking the quiz, the person administering the quiz, other developers using the code...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few advices :

- Python has a code style called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It is a worth reading. Also, you'll find various tools to check that your code is PEP8-compliant like [`pep8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8). You'll also find various other tools to check the quality of your code : pyflakes, pychecker, pylint, etc.
- avoid useless comments. It can be tempting to comment every line you write as you start programming. However, what you are doing adds more noise that it actually helps. As a rule of thumb, ["Code Tells You How, Comments Tell You Why"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). Also, comments are easy to get out of sync with the code (you have places where your code says "25" and the comment says "10", how confusing).
- you can add an argument to [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input) so that you don't have to call `print` before.
- your `while question < 10` loop looks like it could/should be a for loop : `for question in range(10):` (and no need for an initialisation nor for a incrementation in the loop). Also, as a side-note, the convention in Python is to use `_` for throw-away values, thus, the loop could be written : `for _ in range(10):`.
- you should try to use the [`with` keyword](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) whenever you handle files. If you do so, you don't have to call `close` explicitly.
- you should try to ask yourself if your variable describe how you use it. For instance, `class_name` is a proper name for what you do at the beginning. However, it doesn't sound like a proper filename. You could simple create a new variable : `filename = class_name + ".txt"`
- avoid useless tests : in `elif viewscore != "yes".lower()`, the condition will always be true. You could simply write `else`.
- calling `lower()` on "yes" doesn't seem really interesting does it ?

Now, for more "complicated" advices.

You can try to split the logic in small reusable units like functions (or classes). For instance, you could write :

```
def get_int_input():
    while True:
      try:
        return int(input())
      except ValueError:
        print ("That is not a valid answer")
```

Instead of having some code to handle the different possible operations, you could have a structure containing the relevant information : the symbol to be printed and the corresponding operation. You could use a list of tuple to store everything and then, it's easy to pick one at random and use it :

```
import operator

OPERATIONS = [
    (operator.add, "+"),
    (operator.mul, "*"),
    (operator.sub, "-")
    ]

for _ in range(10):
    num1 = random.randint(1,25)
    num2 = random.randint(1,25)
    op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS)
    print("What is", num1, symbol, num2)
    if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):
        print("Correct")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

If you ever need to add one, it's quite easy.

It is also a good habit to use a [`if __name__ == '__main__':` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578308/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-main-method-in-python).

Similarly to what we've done to get an integer input, we can define a function to get a boolean input.

The final code looks like :

```
import random
import operator

OPERATIONS = [
    (operator.add, "+"),
    (operator.mul, "*"),
    (operator.sub, "-")
    ]

NB_QUESTIONS = 10

def get_int_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
      try:
        return int(input(prompt))
      except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid input (integer is expected)")

def get_bool_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt).lower()
        if val == 'yes':
            return True
        elif val == 'no':
            return False
        else:
            print("Not a valid input (yes/no is expected)")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = input("What is your name?").title()
    class_name = input("Which class do you wish to input results for? ")
    print(name, ", Welcome to the OCR Controlled Assessment Maths Test")

    score = 0
    for _ in range(NB_QUESTIONS):
        num1 = random.randint(1,25)
        num2 = random.randint(1,25)
        op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS)
        print("What is", num1, symbol, num2)
        if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

    print("Well done", name, "you scored", score, "/", NB_QUESTIONS)

    filename = class_name + ".txt"

    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(name) + " : " + str(score) + '\n')

    if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            print(f.read())
    else:
        input ("Press any key to exit")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're a bit inconsistent with the whitespace in your output.

For example, when asking for the name, you print the prompt on its own line:

```
print("What is your name?")
name = input().title()
```

But then the following question leaves the cursor on the same line after a trailing space:

```
class_name = input("Which class do you wish to input results for? ")
```

Then, in the quiz itself, you go back to printing the prompt on its own line:

```
else: #If Random Operator = 3/Else, it will ask subtraction questions.
    print("What is", num1, "-", num2)
    ans = num1 - num2

while True:
  try:
    user_ans = int(input())
```

Using `print()` with multiple arguments like this will result in a superfluous space before the comma:

```
print (name, ", Welcome to the OCR Controlled Assessment Maths Test")
```

You've used string concatenation in your program, but the code would be more readable using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

---

@Josay has already given you good advice.  I'd take it a step further and define a `quiz()` function:

```
def quiz(num_questions):
    …
    return score

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = input("What is your name? ").title()
    class_name = input("Which class do you wish to input results for? ")
    print('{}, Welcome to the OCR Controlled Assessment Maths Test'.format(name))

    score = quiz(10)

    filename = class_name + ".txt"
    with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
        f.write("{} : {}\n".format(name, score))
        if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class? "):
            f.seek(0)
            print(f.read(), end='')
        else:
            input("Press any key to exit")
```

Comment: the last section of code poster by 200_success doesnt work can you tell me why ? What is your name? cameron
Which class do you wish to input results for? a
Cameron, Welcome to the OCR Controlled Assessment Maths Test
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python34/test 3.py", line 9, in <module> score = quiz(10) File "C:/Python34/test 3.py", line 2, in quiz return score
NameError: name 'score' is not defined.

Comment: @CameronWilkinson The `…` is a placeholder for the bulk of the quiz code, to be filled in with the loop that asks `num_questions` questions, accepts the answers, and calculates the score.